# Java Webdevelopment Javascript validation workflow?

Tags: java, wicket

I am currently developing a wicket application where in development mode I am in the need to validate the Javascript code that is insert into the rendered output.

I know there are some Java wrappers around for wrapping JSLint (e.g.: [JSLint Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jslint-maven-plugin/), [wro4j](http://code.google.com/p/wro4j/wiki/MavenPluginJsHint)). My problem is, that I also need to validate the JS that is added to buttons and links within the rendered markup, e.g.: `<a href="#" onclick="xxx"></a>`

Edit: I want do this in the build process.

Comment: Do you need to do it as part of build process or at run-time?

Comment: As I edited above: I would like to do it at buildtime, so that these tests would be included in my reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid logic in JavaScript in inline attributes, like onclick="if (condition) {...} else {...}". Better move this logic in a function in .js file and just call it : onclick="doSomething()".
This way you can use any linter tool at build time.

Comment: Well, I agree. But unfortunatelly, the apache wicket project is making heavily use of the above mentioned by you ...

Comment: The good news is that this is no more the case in Wicket 6.0. We reworked it to use event listeners.

Comment: Accepting your answer and looking forward to more propper solutions in Wicket 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a parser which extracts all javascripts found in a page (as part of a build process, wouldn't recommand to do it on run-time). Associate found js with a metadata describing the location of that javascript and after that perform the jslint or jshint analysis on all found javascript using any of the tools mentioned by you.

Comment: Yes, but parsing will be hard to accomplish, as some js errors might be caused because of not propperly enclosing "'" and """ or "`" ...

This circumstance actually is the cause for my question...

Comment: ..and I intended to avoid building my own stuff for this, but use a tool out of let's say: a community...

Comment: This use-case is very custom. It is very unlikely that there is a tool which will do all those things.